# Using customer Marshal function for type with dynamodbattributes.MarshalMap in Go

Tags: json, go, amazon-dynamodb

I have a type called `Period` that looks like this:

```
type Period struct {
    Year int
    Month int
    Day int
}

func (period *Period) String() string {
    if Day == 0 {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%d-%02d", period.Year, period.Month)
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("%d-%02d-%02d", period.Year, period.Month, period.Day)
}

func (period *Period) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(period.String()), nil
}

func (period *Period) UnmarshalJSON(raw []byte) error {
    parsed, err := ParsePeriod(string(raw))
    *period = *parsed
    return err
}
```

The problem I'm having is that if I have a struct with a `*Period` in it, calling `dynamodbattributes.MarshalMap` does not marshal/unmarshal it in a way I'd like. For example,

```
type testStruct struct {
    Period *Period `json:"period,string"`
}

p := testStruct{Period: &Period{Year: 2020, Month: 7, Day: 31}}
attrs, _ := dynamodbattributes.MarshalMap(&p)
fmt.Printf("Attributes: %v\n", attrs)
```

will produce:

```
Attributes: map["period"] {
  M: {
    Year: {
      N: "2020"
    },
    Month: {
      N: "7"
    },
    Day: {
      N: "31"
    }
  }
}
```

I'd prefer the call to produce:

```
Attributes: map["period"] {
    S: "2020-07-31"
}
```

Is there a way I can make this happen without hard-coding the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think dynamodbattributes.MarshalMap uses another custom functions:
`MarshalDynamoDBAttributeValue` and `UnmarshalDynamoDBAttributeValue` instead of `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/#UnixTime

Comment: That appears to only apply to the `time.Time` type. My type is a custom type rather than a `time.Time`.

Comment: I think @isavinof means you may implement these methods for your custom type, using UnixTime as example.